# DateTimeOffset default value

Tags: default, datetimeoffset

I would like to set default value to DateTimeOffset  - it should not be DateTime.Now but rather DateTime.MinValue or default(DateTime)

Any thoughts how can I do it? This code:

```
DateTimeOffset d = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MinValue)
```

throws an exception

Comment: What do you mean by "set default value to DateTimeOffset"? And what exception are you seeing?

Comment: So doesn't `default(DateTimeOffset)` do what you want, then?

Comment: "it should not be DateTime.Now". I don't know if the default value for `DateTimeOffset`´s Date property used to be `DateTime.Now` years ago, but today the default value is `DateTimeOffset.MinValue`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason this code throws an exception for you is that you're presumably in a time zone which is ahead of UTC - so when `DateTime.MinValue` (which has a `Kind` of `Unspecified`) is converted to UTC, it's becoming invalid. The conversion is specified in the documentation:

> If the value of `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, the `DateTime` property of the new instance is set equal to `dateTime`, and the `Offset` property is set equal to the offset of the local system's current time zone.

You could just specify the offset explicitly though:

```
DateTimeOffset d = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MinValue, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

That won't result in any conversion... but I believe it's exactly equivalen to `default(DateTimeOffset)`. (It's more explicit, mind you - often a good thing.)

You might also want to consider using `DateTimeOffset?` and specifying `null` for the absence of a "real" value, instead of just using a dummy value.

Comment: What if my offset is say like 5 hours?

Comment: @Urasquirrel: Then create a timespan of 5 hours for the offset.

Comment: What about DateTimeOffset d = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;

Comment: @PavelPopov: I believe that would give the equivalent value, yes. Personally I somewhat prefer my explicit version, but then I'd actually prefer to use Noda Time anyway :)